# Golang: Make function and third param

Tags: go

What is the difference between:

```
   x := make([]int, 5, 10)    
   x := make([]int, 5)   
   x := [5]int{}
```

I know that `make` allocates an array and returns a slice that refers to that array. I don't understand where it can be used?

I can't find a good example that will clarify the situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x := make([]int, 5)` Makes **slice** of `int` with length 5 and capacity 5 (same as length).

`x := make([]int, 5, 10)` Makes **slice** of `int` with length 5 and capacity 10.

`x := [5]int{}` Makes **array** of `int` with length 5.

### Slices

If you need to append more items than *capacity* of slice using `append` function, go runtime will allocate new *underlying* array and copy existing one to it. So if you know about estimated length of your slice, better to use explicit capacity declaration. It will consume more memory for underlying array at the beginning, but safe cpu time for many allocations and array copying.
You can explore how `len` and `cap` changes while `append`, using that simple test on <kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Y25rolYvgZ)</kbd>
Every time when `cap` value changed, new array allocated

### Arrays

Array size is fixed, so if you need to grow array you have to create new one with new length and copy your old array into it by your own.

There are some great articles about slices and arrays in go:
http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals
http://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 1):

The second line will allocate 10 int's worth memory at the very beginning, but returning you a slice of 5 int's. The second line does not stand less memory, it saves you another memory allocation if you need to expand the slice to anything not more than 10 * load_factor.